# How to access Firebase Realtime Database in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase Database structure is as follows :

[image: snap]

Multiple user details will be stored in this database. How to access this detail in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to access the 'nAc...13' again? and others data?
That thing is seen as a uid. If you created the database using auth, 
use `firebase.auth().uid` to access it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firebase user get to store data as uid of user so you can reuse this data with

```
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference;
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseRefrence_user;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

private String userUid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mFirebaseDatabaseRefrence_users = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(userUid);

    ValueEventListener users = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };

    mFirebaseDatabaseRefrence_user.addValueEventListener(users);
}
```